# How to implement a login with firestore using collections data without using firebase authentication

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, angular-dart

```
  void signIn() async {
    String errorMessages ='';
    bool status = false;
    if(_formkey.currentState.validate()){

      Firestore.instance.collection("users").where('email', isEqualTo: this.emailInputController.text).where('password', isEqualTo: this.pwdInputController.text).getDocuments().then((value) => status = true).catchError((err) => status = false);
      if(status = true){
        Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(this.emailInputController.text)
        .get().then((DocumentSnapshot res) => {
          if(res["role"] == 2){
            print("Manager")
          }
          else if(res["role"] == 3){
            print("Umpire")
          }
        });
      } else {
        print("Not done");
      }
    }
  }
```

This code gives an error. Can anyone help me? I think it is not working firebase part properly.

Comment: "This code gives an error." What error do you get? Please click the edit link under your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

`if(status = true)` is one error, I can find.
It should be `if(status == true)`.
I think you must have already fixed it.